# VIDEO_SCHEDULER_INTERNAL_ERROR [BSOD]

Tags: windows-8.1, bsod

I get this BSOD while im playing any video game. I am usally playing for about 15 minutes before this happens, but recently i have been getting it whenever i start a game.

**Specs:** Corsair CX 750M, 750W PSUATX 12V V2.3, 80 Plus Bronze, Modular. 4x 6+2pin P

Intel Core i5-4670K Processor Socket-LGA1150, Quad Core, 3.4GHz, 6MB, 84W, HD460

MSI Z87-G45 Gaming, Socket-1150 ATX, Z87, DDR3, 3xPCIe-x16, SLI/CFX, VGA,HDMI,DP,K

Cooler Master Seidon 120M CPU Kjøler 775/1150/1155/1156/1366/2011, AM2(+)/AM3(+)/FM1, 6

Crucial DDR3 BallistiX Sport 16GB KIT 16GB kit (8GBx2), Sport,1600MHz, 1.5V, CL9-9-9-24

Gainward GeForce GTX 770 2GB PhysX CUDA PCI-Express 3.0, with Batman Arkham Origins

Kingston SSDNow V300 120GB 2.5" OEM SATA3.0, 7mm, 450MB/450MB/s read/write, SandForce

**minidump:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/7qit1qg5tcjttue/061615-13703-01.dmp?dl=0

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please tag for the OS your using. Have you changed the video card rescent or changed the driver for the video card rescent? Are they beta video drivers? Do you know your running load GPU temperatures? What exactally occurs visually, and to the computer before the bsod, like screen messes up?  What kind of resolutions are your running the game in (like 3k-4k)?

Comment: A scan of the web shows that general error occuring when just playing video only also, , sort of new for 8 , could be related to cpu and the regular MB ram. Overclocked computers running fine when put to stock also. Weird one No one explored the power options either, which allow for video playback (multimedia) to have different cpu responce, which (i think) is classed somewhere as a scheduler .  And no i did not look at the dump because that has not solutioned things out on the web yet.  IF you are somehow overclocked or have XMP memory profile , then it might be a good time to hard test both.

Answer (score 1):

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

VIDEO_SCHEDULER_INTERNAL_ERROR (119)
The video scheduler has detected that fatal violation has occurred. This resulted
in a condition that video scheduler can no longer progress. Any other values after
parameter 1 must be individually examined according to the subtype.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000001, The driver has reported an invalid fence ID.
Arg2: 000000000004e945
Arg3: 000000000004e964
Arg4: ffffe001633df540

Debugging Details:
------------------


SYSTEM_SKU:  To be filled by O.E.M.

SYSTEM_VERSION:  1.0

BIOS_DATE:  09/03/2013

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  Z87-G45 GAMING (MS-7821)

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  1.0

BUGCHECK_P1: 1

BUGCHECK_P2: 4e945

BUGCHECK_P3: 4e964

BUGCHECK_P4: ffffe001633df540

CPU_COUNT: 4

CPU_MHZ: d48

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3c

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x119

PROCESS_NAME:  svchost.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  6

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10069.9 amd64fre

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 watchdog!WdLogEvent5_WdCriticalError
02 dxgmms1!VidSchDdiNotifyInterruptWorker
03 dxgmms1!VidSchDdiNotifyInterrupt
04 dxgkrnl!DxgNotifyInterruptCB
05 nvlddmkm
06 0x0
07 0x0
08 0x0
09 0x0
0a nvlddmkm
0b 0x0


IMAGE_NAME:  nvlddmkm.sys

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x119_1_DRIVER_REPORTED_INVALID_FENCE_ID_nvlddmkm!Unknown_Function

BUCKET_ID:  0x119_1_DRIVER_REPORTED_INVALID_FENCE_ID_nvlddmkm!Unknown_Function

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x119_1_DRIVER_REPORTED_INVALID_FENCE_ID_nvlddmkm!Unknown_Function

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x119_1_driver_reported_invalid_fence_id_nvlddmkm!unknown_function

    Loaded symbol image file: nvlddmkm.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\nvlddmkm.sys
    Image name: nvlddmkm.sys
    Timestamp:        Thu May 28 04:49:51 2015
```

[A fence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559758%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is explained here:

> A fence is an instruction that contains 64 bits of data and an address. 
>   The display miniport driver can insert a fence in the direct memory
>   access (DMA) stream that is sent to the graphics processing unit
>   (GPU). When the GPU reads the fence, the GPU writes the fence data at
>   the specified fence address. However, before the GPU can write the
>   fence data to memory, it must ensure that all of the pixels from the
>   primitives that precede the fence instruction are retired and properly
>   written to memory.

As I suggested in your 1st question, update the BIOS, try to put the GPU into a different PCIe x16 slot and try different driver versions. Also do a memory test with [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/#downiso).

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly confident in saying this is a drive issue with your GPU.  Basically something looks as if it is corrupt, have you tried updating any of your Display Adapters drivers to the most recent version?  You can find your Display Adapters in Device Manager.  To get there, go and Right Click on Computer > Properties > then select Device Manager.

Another recommendation would be to scan for Virus'/Malware, sometimes these can cause BSODs.

My final suggestion would be to look at upgrading your BIOS.  To find your BIOS version type the following code in Command Prompt (WARNING: If you're laptop turns off/loses power during a BIOS update, your PC can be become unusable.):

```
wmic bios get smbiosbiosversion
```

Let me know if you have tried these. Or if you need help with completing these actions.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened with me few days ago! I have tried several methods to fix out the problem. Later discovered it was due to the driver update. I simply removed the driver from the control panel and then installed the older version again.

However, for more reference you can see this article from [techcaption](https://techcaption.com/fix-video-scheduler-internal-error-windows/)

However make sure to turn off the automatic updates from Windows 10. The update keeps running on the background which triggers the driver updating feature.